# How to inject a commit hash into a docker container during build?

Tags: git, bazel

The problem I'm ultimately trying to solve is to have a status endpoint return the commit hash of the code that is running. If that is injected into the docker container as an environment variable as inspired by [this blog post](https://blog.alexellis.io/inject-build-time-vars-golang/), it is quite easy from there. How to get Bazel to do this?

Furthermore, the repository on which I'm working contains multiple apps and containers, but I would not want to rebuild (and thus release through CD functionality) any of the containers whose dependant code is unchanged. How to ensure Bazel only executes this rule for containers which actually have a code change?

For clarity, here's an example of dependancies:

```
containerA  containerB
    |           |
 binaryA     binaryB
    |           |
 sourceA     sourceB
     \          /
       sourceC
```

Changes to `sourceA` should result in a new `containerA` but not `containerB` and vice-versa. Changes to `sourceC` should result in new containers for both. These rules should apply without cached build artefacts, so that builds are always repeatable.

As such, using the hash of the head of the repo is likely not possible, so I'm open to alternatives in the same vein.

Comment: AFK by suggest you take a look at stamping and volatile status